# Remove progress bar from html5 video player in full screen

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a video element on my page with code below

```
<video autoplay="" audiovolume="100" src="blob:https%3A//cccxxx.com/ccde5479" class="OT_video-element" style="transform: rotate(0deg); top: -74.4193878173828px; width: 770.440307617188px; height: 577.830230712891px;">Sorry, Web RTC is not available in your browser</video>
```

I want to remove progress bar for this video element, how can i do it?

Comment: i have fixed it using css, let me know if their is any better option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls,
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: you can also use `:fullscreen { style properties }` to apply your style only in mode fullscreen

Comment: This is not the solution, this will only works for Chrome and about Firefox

Answer (score 3):

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Previous approach will only work in some browsers like chrome or safari, but not in firefox or internet explorer
I would suggest building your own video player, that way you'll have the control over the control elements

In this case I only needed the Play/Pause button, so the user couldn't fast forward the video

The HTML

```
<section class="skin">
    <video id="myMovie">
        <source src="video_url"/>
    </video>
    <nav>
        <button id="playButton">Play</button>
    </nav>
</section>
```

The js

```
function loadVideo(){
    myMovie=document.getElementById('myMovie');
    playButton=document.getElementById('playButton');
    playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
}

function playOrPause() {
    if (!myMovie.paused && !myMovie.ended){
        myMovie.pause();
        playButton.innerHTML='Play';
    } else {
        myMovie.play();
        playButton.innerHTML='Pause';
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load',loadVideo,false);
```

The CSS

```
.skin {
    width:640px;
    margin:10px auto;
    padding:5px;
}
nav {
    width:70px;
    height:22px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

(nav tag and css only included to add some styling)

Comment: I added nocontrols to the video tag in the HTML portion, that removed all the controls on the video and I used your play button here to play and pause. That worked for me, hope that solution work for others too.