# Hide time-second scrollbar in video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video, scrollbar

How I can hide time-second scrollbar in video tag using HTML or javaScript:

[image: CHECK SCREENSHOT]

Setting `controls="false"` as suggested by @Praveen removes all controls. I want to remove the time-second scrollbar.

Here is my code:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: `controls="false"`?

Comment: It's remove all options like: start-stop movie, mute option etc. Is it possible to hide only option which makes user can skip movie by few seconds?

Comment: @jww I added my HTML code. I don't know why people closed my question. I searched many time in google solution for my problem and I couldn't found solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742851/remove-progress-bar-from-html5-video-player-in-full-screen

Answer (score 7):

It can be done through css. Add following line in css:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 3):

video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
    display: none 
}

find more details [here](https://github.com/interglobalmedia/custom-html5-video-player/wiki/Creating-A-Custom-HTML5-Video-Player-And-The-Shadow-DOM).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot remove progress bar from the video because it is rendered by browser.

The only way is you use some video player like [Brightcove](https://www.brightcove.com/) or [JWPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/) for example.