# How to hide/disable buttons controls in videojs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, video.js

I have application with [video.js](https://docs.videojs.com/) and vue.

I try to find a way to hide or disable those controls: play button, playback rate, and make the progress bar readonly.

[I the video.js docs](https://docs.videojs.com/) there is `controls: false` which hide all controls bar. and this is not what I want.

I also try to figure out [in typescript DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/video.js/index.d.ts#L1969), in controlBar options there only two properties: volumePanel and fullscreenToggle. nothing about play or progress-bar or rate.

**Edit** I find `controlBar: { playToggle: false }` which hide play button.

But I still find a way to make readonly/disable progressbar.

Any idea how to do it?

My code is looks like this snippet:

```js
Vue.use(VueVideoPlayer)
new Vue({
  el: '#vueapp',
   data() {
      return {
       message: 'Hi from Vue',
        // videojs options
        playerOptions: {
          height: '360',
          autoplay: true,
          muted: true,
          language: 'en',
          
          playbackRates: [0.7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
          sources: [{
            type: "video/mp4",
            // mp4
            src: "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4",
            // webm
            // src: "https://cdn.theguardian.tv/webM/2015/07/20/150716YesMen_synd_768k_vp8.webm"
          }],
          poster: "https://surmon-china.github.io/vue-quill-editor/static/images/surmon-1.jpg",
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      // console.log('this is current player instance object', this.player)
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('dynamic change options', this.player)
        this.player.muted(false)
      }, 2000)
        
    },
    computed: {
      player() {
        return this.$refs.videoPlayer.player
      }
    },
    methods: {
      // listen event
      onPlayerPlay(player) {
        // console.log('player play!', player)
      },
      onPlayerPause(player) {
        // console.log('player pause!', player)
      },
      onPlayerEnded(player) {
        // console.log('player ended!', player)
      },
      onPlayerLoadeddata(player) {
        // console.log('player Loadeddata!', player)
      },
      onPlayerWaiting(player) {
        // console.log('player Waiting!', player)
      },
      onPlayerPlaying(player) {
        // console.log('player Playing!', player)
      },
      onPlayerTimeupdate(player) {
        // console.log('player Timeupdate!', player.currentTime())
      },
      onPlayerCanplay(player) {
        // console.log('player Canplay!', player)
      },
      onPlayerCanplaythrough(player) {
        // console.log('player Canplaythrough!', player)
      },
      // or listen state event
      playerStateChanged(playerCurrentState) {
        // console.log('player current update state', playerCurrentState)
      },
      // player is ready
      playerReadied(player) {
        // seek to 10s
        console.log('example player 1 readied', player)
        player.currentTime(10)
        // console.log('example 01: the player is readied', player)
      }
    }
 })
```

```html
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/video.js@6.6.2/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-video-player@5.0.0/src/custom-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Include the videojs library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/6.6.2/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<!-- videojs JS Vue -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-video-player@5.0.0/dist/vue-video-player.js"></script>

<div id="vueapp">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <video-player class="vjs-custom-skin"
                  ref="videoPlayer"
                  :options="playerOptions"
                  :playsinline="true"
                  @play="onPlayerPlay($event)"
                  @pause="onPlayerPause($event)"
                  @ended="onPlayerEnded($event)"
                  @loadeddata="onPlayerLoadeddata($event)"
                  @waiting="onPlayerWaiting($event)"
                  @playing="onPlayerPlaying($event)"
                  @timeupdate="onPlayerTimeupdate($event)"
                  @canplay="onPlayerCanplay($event)"
                  @canplaythrough="onPlayerCanplaythrough($event)"
                  @ready="playerReadied"
                  @statechanged="playerStateChanged($event)">
  </video-player>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution is here https://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/options.html

Comment: no really. where say I can make progress bar to be readonly? or where can I hide the play button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742851/remove-progress-bar-from-html5-video-player-in-full-screen

Comment: no. I don't want to remove. just make it disable, unclickable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try those in the options:

```
 controlBar: {
    playToggle: false,
    captionsButton: false,
    chaptersButton: false,            
    subtitlesButton: false,
    remainingTimeDisplay: false,
    progressControl: {
      seekBar: true
    },
    fullscreenToggle: false,
    playbackRateMenuButton: false,
  },
```

and make the `ProgressControl` disable:

```
 mounted() {
   this.$refs.videoPlayer.player.controlBar.progressControl.disable();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
 <video-player controlBar={false} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
player.controlBar.fullscreenToggle.dispose();
```

You can use:

```
.disable() > shows the button but is not active to iterate
.hide() > hides the button, but the element is in the DOM
.dispose() > removes the element entirely
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the whole `control bar` for example when paused, just add this css.

`Player.css`

```
.vjs-has-started.vjs-user-inactive .vjs-control-bar {
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.1s, opacity 0.1s;
}
```

`Player.tsx`

```
import "./Player.css"
```

For buttons, just use button selectors such as `.vjs-button`, `.vjs-big-play-button`, `.vjs-audio-button`, and other class names to locate them and style them later in the `CSS` file.